# Will the following load my XML file

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010

I am having a problem with the following - it does not appear to load my XML file.  I want to load in the file and then use XMLNodeLlist to iterate through it and store my values.  The XML File is in my Visual Studio 2010 solution.  Is there something I am missing in the Path?

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();

public Test()
{

    xml.LoadXml(@"C:\Users\testuser\Desktop\TestWebsite\TestData.xml");
   ...more code
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[XmlDocument.LoadXml(stirng xml)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml.aspx) is not expecting a file path but an actual xml string.
You could use [XmlDocument.Load()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.load.aspx) and pass it a FileStream to you your document or a file path:

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load(@"C:\Users\testuser\Desktop\TestWebsite\TestData.xml");
// or
xml.Load(File.OpenRead(@"C:\Users\testuser\Desktop\TestWebsite\TestData.xml"));
```

Even better than that would be to use the new [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb538371.aspx) object which has a load method that works directly with a file path, this is the preferred way of interacting with Xml in later versions of .NET and would recommend using this approach:

```
XDocument doc1 = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\testuser\Desktop\TestWebsite\TestData.xml", LoadOptions.None);
```

Comment: was thinking that was the case Andy from doing some more googling :( - whats the best way to load in a File of XML Andy do you know?

Comment: You can also pass the path directly to Load

Comment: @KOL - I would really suggest using XDocument now as this is really the preferred method of working with XML in .NET now and it also give you access to lots of Linq goodness.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque - absolutely right, I have amended the answer.

Comment: @AndyRose - Thanks - what is the using directive for it?  System.Xml doesnt find it for me?